# R - title plots based on nested lists

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have 2 lists, and inside each are two more lists containing data frames (in other words, nested lists). I want plot each data frame and title it based on the names of both the primary and nested lists.

For example, say we have:

```
a=list(
  list(a=data.frame(x=rpois(5,1),y=rpois(5,1)),
       b=data.frame(x=rpois(5,1),y=rpois(5,1))),
  list(c=data.frame(x=rpois(5,1),y=rpois(5,1)),
       d=data.frame(x=rpois(5,1),y=rpois(5,1))))
```

And we have the names of the primary list:

```
names(a)=c("alpha","bravo")
```

Inside the two primary lists `alpha` and `bravo`, we have two more lists, `charlie` and `delta`:

```
for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  names(a[[i]])=c("charlie","delta") }
```

I can use `lapply` to loop through each list and plot the data frames, but I am having trouble getting the titles to combine the name of the primary list (`alpha` and `bravo`) and the nested list (`charlie` and `delta`) for each data frame. For instance, in this case, I would like to have four plots called: `alpha_charlie`, `alpha_delta`,`bravo_charlie`, and `bravo_delta`.

```
lapply(a,function(i) {
  lapply(names(i), function(j) { 
    ggplot()+
      geom_point(data=i[[j]],aes(x,y))+
      opts(title=paste(names(i),j,sep="_")) #Here is where I am struggling!
    } ) } )
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use lapply on an indexing sequence instead of the names themselves.

```
lapply(seq(a), function(i){
    lapply(seq(a[[i]]), function(j){
        ggplot() +
        geom_point(data = a[[i]][[j]], aes(x, y))+
        opts(title = paste(names(a)[i], names(a[[i]])[j], sep = "_"))
        })})
```

Comment: Works great.  I tried to do something similar with for loops but it fell apart..similar approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My preference would be to stick with `for` loops in this situation. Doing so makes it easy to save the plots into a new list and then print them all at once using `grid.arrange` and `do.call`.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_list = list() # Save plots to list.

for (name_1 in names(a)) {
    for (name_2 in names(a[[name_1]])) {
        title_string = paste(name_1, name_2, sep="_")

        plt = ggplot(data=a[[name_1]][[name_2]], aes(x=x, y=y)) +
              geom_point() +
              opts(title=title_string)

        plot_list[[title_string]] = plt
    }
}

library(gridExtra)
png("plots.png", height=600, width=600)
do.call(grid.arrange,  plot_list)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your first lapply, you've lost the names, so this winds up being yucky. Dason gave you a good fix.

However, I think you'd be much better served converting the list of lists of data.frames into a single data.frame! and use faceting!

```
nested.fun <- function(l) {
  out <- ldply(l, data.frame)
  names(out)[1] <- 'inner.id'
  return(out)
}

one.df <- ldply(a, nested.fun)

ggplot(one.df, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+facet_grid(.id~inner.id)
```